# How to hide the path immediate overlap without hiding intersection overlap?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making a painting app, and using the canvas path as a brush:

```
function onMove(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from position
    pos=getPosition(event); 
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to position 
    ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
}
```

I'm stuck between in a dilemma, if I join all the paths into one I lose intersection overlap, and if I draw them real time separately I get those start/end overlaps spheres.

[image]

Is there a clean way I can solve this problem?  Thank you.

Comment: You could build a single path from the drawn paths, and render them in one go using `ctx.beginPath();` and `ctx.closePath();`. Maybe you also render to an "in progress" canvas you can clear on the go and on release render the result on the persistent canvas.

Comment: I would lose the intersection overlap, then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, then it is getting complicated since we are dealing with alpha values here..

Basicly you can draw the "missing part" of the new line in a buffer canvas by using `destination-in` and `source-in` blend modes.

The idea is: to "compute" the overlapp of the N-1 the Nth line and then only draw line N outside this overlap:
(for demonstation the Nth line will be drawn in red.)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas2.width = 300
canvas2.height = 300
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 30
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.lineJoin = "round"



function drawLine1(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 250);
  ctx.stroke();
}
function drawLine2(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(100, 250);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 50);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// draw image until line n-1 on screen
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 100);
ctx.lineTo(250, 100); // 1st
ctx.lineTo(250, 250); // 2nd
ctx.lineTo(100, 250); // n-1
ctx.stroke();

// clear buffer canvas and setup
ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
ctx2.lineWidth = 30
ctx2.lineCap = 'round';
ctx2.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
// draw line n-1 on buffer in opaque color
ctx2.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
drawLine1(ctx2)

// draw line n on buffer in "destination-in" blend mode opaque
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
ctx2.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
drawLine2(ctx2)

// draw line n on buffer in "source-out" blend mode and original color
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
ctx2.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)';
drawLine2(ctx2)

ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0 ,0)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

It is not perfect, but it is a starting point..

Comment: Thank you very much, this exactly what I need.